# Hunger Games-style book about a world with different alien species fighting

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, dystopia

Around 10 years ago, I read a new book about an entire world, with different alien species all fighting. I remember the enemies being spider-like.
The protagonist learns that they are being watched and I think finds hints of it all being televised.
It was a part one of an unfinished story kind of thing.

Very *Lost* meets *The Hunger Games*. And I believe it had a title like *Bone Arrow* or something like that.

Comment: So are the spider aliens the ones running the games? Or are the enemies inside the game? Or a bit of both?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21412023-the-arrow has some matching details, but it's 2014. And a graphic novel.

Comment: I remember it being a different species that couldn't communicate at all, and they were basically at war.  But the watchers were something else entirely. Every participant was like a primitive society. Except for the hints of who was watching.

Comment: Was the protagonist human or an alien? And were they male, female, or neither?

Comment: The protagonist was a male alien I believe.

Comment: Was it a single representative of each species, or a group?  Were they paired off to fight, tournament style, or all thrown together melee style?  Did they use weapons they arrived with, were they provided weapons, or did they have to fashion their own weapons?

Comment: It was setup like the story followed a tribe of the male. And they were defending the tribe from a tribe of the spiders. I don't remember how they got their.

Comment: Maybe one of the Bone World books by Peadar Ó Guilín?

Answer (score 4):

It was the first book of the Bone World series, *[Inferior](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/2571305-the-inferior)*, by Peadar Ó Guilín.
Thank you a bunch [@Danny Mc G](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265413/hunger-games-style-book-about-a-world-with-different-alien-species-fighting/265429#comment731405_265413)!

> STOPMOUTH AND HIS family know of no other life than the daily battle to survive. To live, they must hunt rival species, or negotiate flesh-trade with those who crave meat of the freshest human kind. It is a savage, desperate existence. And for Stopmouth, considered slowwitted hunt-fodder by his tribe, the future looks especially bleak. But then, on the day he is callously betrayed by his brother, a strange and beautiful woman falls from the sky. It is a moment that will change his destiny, and that of all humanity, forever.

Comment: You will be able to accept your self-answer 48 hours after you asked the question, so a little under two days, by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].