# Book with a boy and a world of monsters, who comes upon a woman who is from a dome on the surface

Tags: story-identification, books

There's a book I'm trying to remember. It follows a boy from a tribe in a world of monsters, their brother is . The tribe comes across a woman that speaks a different language and they take her in as a slave. As they get to know each other he treats her kindly and at a point they find a universal translator. The woman is actually from a group of people that live in a dome around the surface of the Earth while the tribe lives under an artificial sky.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Also, the follow sentence appears incomplete; could you complete or rephrase it for us? _"It follows a boy from a tribe in a world of monsters, their brother is ."_

Answer (score 4):

I think this is *The Inferior* by Peader O'Guilan, the first of his *Bone World* trilogy

Blurb from [Fantastic Fiction](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/g/peadar-o-guilin/inferior.htm):

> STOPMOUTH AND HIS family know of no other life than the daily battle to survive. To live, they must hunt rival species, or negotiate flesh-trade with those who crave meat of the freshest human kind. It is a savage, desperate existence. And for Stopmouth, considered slowwitted hunt-fodder by his tribe, the future looks especially bleak. But then, on the day he is callously betrayed by his brother, a strange and beautiful woman falls from the sky. It is a moment that will change his destiny, and that of all humanity, forever.

Comment: Self-answer dupe at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265413/hunger-games-style-book-about-a-world-with-different-alien-species-fighting/265429#265429 although https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81212/science-fiction-book-with-low-tech-humans-eating-other-sentient-species/141893#141893 is a much better (but unaccepted) anwer.